# Modal window with bootstrap doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal window built with bootstrap on my wordpress site. 
When i click on button windows appears, but if i click on "close" button or "x" button the page crashes. You can see that and try on my  [site](http://www.housefit.com.ro/test/).
Please help me! 
I use "Bootstrap modal" plugin!
I have included bootstrap.min.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Always try to place a modal's HTML code in a top-level position in your document to avoid other components affecting the modal's appearance and/or functionality.

2) please, copy the Modal code from bootstrap rather than anywhere else to make sure you have at least all the minimum said from bootstrap Modal
    http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

3) do not remove the class or role defined by it unless you have such functionality created by you own

4) It comes under number 1. but again make sure you have script, I do not see on your's